# Алгоритм определения радиуса окружности, в которую можно вписать текст

Tags: алгоритм

Недавно тут задавали [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/485946/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-textview), ответа на который ни автор, ни я не нашел. Суть вопроса состоит в том, чтобы выводить текст, вписанным в окружность. И я решил заморочиться, и реализовать это.
Я не могу придумать алгоритм для того, чтобы вписать текст в окружность, зная высоту линии.
Ничего не приходит в голову, кроме как перебором пытаться найти оптимальный вариант.
Вот, собственно, чего я хочу добиться:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *вписать текст в окружность, зная высоту линии* - а что за высота? Размер шрифта какой-то заданный или можно его менять? И крайний случай - есть текст наподобие *я текст немного треугольнотреугольный*, т.е. текст, которым можно нормально заполнить верхнюю часть круга, но который уже не подходит для нижней части круга - что делать? Нормального круга без обрезания слов у нас не получится. И обязательно в верхней части каждая строчка должна быть больше предыдущей? Или главное чтобы границы текста создавали очертание круга? т.е. текст может быть лестнично-круглым

Comment: @BOPOH, да, ньюансов много... Думаю, треугольный текст чтобы заполнял верхнюю часть, Размер шрифта - константа, а радиус круга должен меняться.

Comment: а если забить на сам круг? смещаем текст в вашем примере вправо - получается треугольник, т.е. если сделать такой треугольник - мы получим примерно круг. "Примерно", т.к. проделав то же самое с ромбом мы точно так же получим тот самый треугольник, но "ромб" с натяжкой можно назвать "кругом". Хотя вставив между словами дополнительное пространство в "ромбе" мы можем получить наш "круг". Такой подход подойдет? Тогда и алгоритм несложный: с начала строки перемещаем текст вверх, а с конца - вниз так, чтобы наш "треугольник" сохранялся. Когда сохранить не получится - получили наш "круг"

Comment: @BOPOH Вспоминается армейское, что в военное время Pi может достигать 4. Так и у вас, при "складывании" круга получается треугольник/ромб ;-)

Answer (score 7):

По моему тут всё просто. Зная высоту строки и её порядковый номер, мы можем рассчитать необходимую ширину (хорду круга):  `ширина = корень из (высота*номер)*(2*радиус -высота*номер)`. (Я могу ошибиться, но я думаю вы способны вычислить длину хорды самостоятельно)
Дальше задача сводится к тому, чтоб вписать текст вы эту ширину.

Если же вы не знаете радиус заранее, вы можете рассчитать его исходя из того, что вам нужно вписать площадь текста в площадь круга: `радиус = корень из (общая ширина * высота строки / пи)`

Добавьте допуски, учитывающие что часть слов придется переносить на следующую строку, чтобы все вписалось. Выравнивание текста нужно по обеим сторонам.

Comment: .. и повторять пока не впишется все с большим допуском если не вписалось (из-за особенностей переноса например).

Comment: @Krom Stern зачем? Можно просто заранее взять достаточно большой допуск, подобранный методом научного тыка. Выравнивание по обоим сторонам нивелирует эффект слишком большого допуска. Так же можно искать самое длинное слово в тексте и брать допуск исходя из него, но имхо это излишне

Comment: Как человек работавший в верстке журналов, скажу - одна лишняя буква в полосе способна удлинить текст на несколько строк, и все из-за неудачных переносов. Никто не будет подбирать методом тыка каждый раз, когда у заказчика опять что-то не влезет. Просто добавьте рекурсию с бОльшим запасом в конец - это не сложно. А если брать просто большой допуск, то может оставаться слишком много пустого места в низу круга. Не критикую вас ни в чем, только дополняю ответ.

Comment: И нужно писать модуль переносов с учётом нужного языка, т.к. целиковые слова красиво впишутся только при очень мелком шрифте. А выравнивание а-ля Word, делая пробелы между словами разной ширины и всё впишется как нужно

Answer (score 1):

Пусть задан текст и радиус круга. Научимся вписывать текст в круг. Для этого надо будет провести в круге горизонтальные линии на расстоянии высоты шрифта друг от друга. У каждой линии вычисляется её длина внутри круга. Зная длину линии можно понять сколько слов на неё поместится. Строка за строкой заполняем линии. Если текст поместился на линии в круге, возвращаем истину, иначе ложь.

Очевидно, что если для какого-то радиуса *r* текст поместился, то он поместится и для любого большего радиуса. Аналогично, если текст не помещается в радиус *r*, то он не поместится и в любой меньший радиус.

Отыщем минимум радиуса при котором текст помещается двоичным поиском. Задача решена. Думаю что на практике будет достаточно десяти попыток, чтобы отыскать нужный радиус.